# How to create a basic bookmarklet that mimics Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, bookmarklet

I know Selenium, Java/Python, XPaths etc and am looking for a basic "skeleton" Javascript bookmarklet that lets me perform simple Selenium like operations on the current page, e.g. (pseudocode),

```
begin
document.click ("//button[@class='buy']")
wait 2 seconds
document.entertext("//form[@class='name']", "John Smith")
wait 2 seconds
document.check("//radiobutton[@class='agrees']")
end
```

Googling returns an infinite number of articles but so far I haven't found anything that addresses this situation.

The reason for my request is that I enter the exact same (static) values in webforms day after day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase Well, I don't know Javascript so that is where I am stuck. That is, since I can code I can "passively" probably read JS and make minor adjustments but I can't "actively" create something form scratch. Hence why I asked for a skeleton example that can get me going. Thank you.

Comment: It wouldn't work if there's a navigation between step 1 and 2 and it looks like there probably is. Also your selectors are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? The code below can be saved into index.html, pressing a "Test" button simulates what you described — "buy" is clicked, then 2 seconds later the name is entered, and 2 seconds later "agree" is clicked.

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<button class="test" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<button class="buy" onclick="unhide_form()">Click me</button>
<form id="main_form" style="display: none">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input class="name" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" placeholder="Your name"><br>
  <input type="radio" id="agrees" class="agrees" value="agr">
    <label for="agrees">Agrees</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<script>
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function unhide_form() {
    var f = document.getElementById("main_form")
    f.style = "display: block"
}
async function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("buy")[0].click()
    await sleep(2000)
    document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value = "John"
    await sleep(2000)
    document.getElementsByClassName("agrees")[0].click()
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Not sure if that'll be enough for the real task you're facing; if not, tell more details, like the URL of the site you're visiting, the automation steps (fields you're filling, buttons you're clicking, etc), and what exactly fails.

---

EDIT: I see. I'm new to doing this in javascript as well, so I also learned something new in the process :) Here's the code:

```
function submit_wayback_machine_form(url_to_save) {
    elems = document.evaluate('//*[@id="web-save-url-input"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
    elem = elems.iterateNext()  //elem is now the text field
    elem.value = url_to_save    //changing its text to URL we want
    
    elems = document.evaluate('//input[starts-with(@value, "SAVE PAGE")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
    elem = elems.iterateNext()
    elem.click()
}

submit_wayback_machine_form("https://google.com")
```

Tested it, appears to be working: [image: screenshot]

Also, here are the useful links I got the info from:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript — took the xpath code from this page;
2. https://devhints.io/xpath — a nice cheatsheet for XPath (maybe you already knew all this, but even if so, I'm saving it for myself for the future reference)
3. also, I recommend "XPath Helper" extension for Chrome, helps me quickly test whether my XPath is correct: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

---

EDIT2:

> Does Javascript not support something like element.click (Xpath)? Why the iteration and evaluation of everything?

That's just how it works, we document.evaluate(...) the XPATH expression first, and then we iterate through results (multiple elements may fit the same XPATH expression).

If I had to simplify it a bit for a more convenient usage... How about this?

```
//this one returns the first fitting element
function getFirstElementByXPATH(xpath) {
    elems = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    elem = elems.iterateNext()
    return elem
}

//this one returns an array of fitting elements
function getAllElementsByXPATH(xpath) { 
    elems = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
    results = []
    while (1) {
        elem = elems.iterateNext()
        if (elem != null) {
            results.push(elem)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

Then, you can use

```
getFirstElementByXPATH("//li/div/button/span").click()
//or
getAllElementsByXPATH("//li/div/button/span")[0].click()
//or
element = getFirstElementByXPATH("//my_custom_expression_1")
element.click()
elements = getAllElementsByXPATH("//my_custom_expression_2")
elements[0].click()
elements[1].value = "abc"
```

Hopefully it's convenient enough!

Comment: I extracted everything between the script tags and created a bookmark that I prefixed javascript: (so `javascript:async function…`) and then saved all your code as index.html and opened the file in Safari. Clicking `Click me` shows the form as expected. Clicking `Test` fills in a name and checks `Agree` but doesn't seem to click `Submit` (because when I manually click Submit the form is cleared and hidden).

Comment: However, clicking my bookmark has no effect at all, and that is my end goal (i.e., that the form should be filled in and submitted when I click the bookmark). Here is a good example form to work with https://web.archive.org/save/ - would be great if the bookmarklet could enter a URL, uncheck the checkbox and then click Save.

Comment: And is it possible to use XPaths instead of IDs? Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. I edited my answer above; let me know if you need anything else! (I'll read it tomorrow though, 2am for me already)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It still seems very convoluted and hard to expand. Does Javascript not support something like `element.click (Xpath)`?  Why the iteration and evaluation of everything? Could you try to create something more similar to the pseudocode I included in my question? Thank you.

Comment: Good evening, hensti. I'm afraid there's no standard functionality like element.click(xpath), but I made a custom function (check out EDIT2 in my reply), which allows calling a function like this: getFirstElementByXPATH("//my_xpath").click()

Comment: I am still not following you. Xpaths are typically unique (if there are multiple elements with the exact same Xpath you can number them in the Xpath `//div/p[1]` or so. You can assume the return value is a singleNode, not a nodeSet. In that case, wouldn't something like `document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).click()` work?

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript :
---
The XPathResult object returned is a node-set of matched nodes which will behave as an iterator, allowing us to access the individual nodes contained by using the iterateNext() method of the XPathResult.

Once we have iterated over all of the individual matched nodes, iterateNext() will return null. 
---
So, regardless of whether it returns one result, like with //div/p[1], or multiple results, like with //div/p, it would seem you'll have to iterate anyway.

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult `XPathResult.singleNodeValue Read only

    A Node representing the value of the single node result, which may be null.
`

Comment: Well then, if you find a way to do it without iterateNext(), that'd be great :)
I haven't touched javascript for many weeks now (except for this little code snippet above), so that's as far as I can help. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

In general it looks like this:

```
(() => {
  document.querySelector('.buy')?.click();
  setTimeout(() => somethingElse(), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.agrees')?.click(), 4000);
})()
```

But I can't tell what the something else is and it won't work if there's a navigation between steps

Comment: I understand the first line but can you explain line 2 and 3? They seem very convoluted for just a timeout and a click/check. Thank you.

Comment: setTimeout takes a function and a timeout in milliseconds. `() => somethingElse()` is an arrow function, you can also use the old-fashioned functions is those look less convoluted which looks like `function(){...}`

Comment: Why do you need to send functions/function pointers as argument? Is there some advantage with that compared to the more imperative way I wrote my pseudo code in?

Comment: That's the only way to get a 2 / 4 second delay. Javascript doesn't have a time.sleep() like python does

Comment: So `document.querySelector('.buy')?.click();` interacts with the element? And click, which I assume applies to buttons, can be replaced with other functions to check a box or insert a text? Can you include these functions in your example?

Comment: What is `.buy`?

Comment: Can you explain the setTimeout lines a bit more detailed? The first line creates a function called setTimeout? But why is does the second line seem to both include a timeout and an action? Couldn't it be written more like the pseudocode I included in my question with the timeout on one line and the action on a another line? Thank you.

Comment: Yes but it's often a click. `.buy` is an element with buy in the class list. The second line does the action in a setTimeout because you want it to happen after waiting 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not a JS bookmarklet, but the [Browserflow](https://browserflow.app/) extension/service might be better to "enter the exact same (static) values in webforms day after day."

I used Browserflow to scrape data from paginated results that required clicking a button to append more results.

No JavaScript knowledge is required (although you can use JavaScript to do more complicated things if you want.)

Note this is a paid service with a limited free tier.